# How can I rename strings of indices?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking forward to rename the indices names 'Juan Gonzalez' to 'Jason', 'Jorge Sanchez' to 'George' and 'Miguel Sanz' to 'Michael'

```
                              age     height(cm)  weight(kg)
 People
 Juan Gonzalez                  22     181        60
 Jorge Sanchez                  34     190        84
 Miguel Sanz                    50     166        59
```

I thought it worked like when renaming columns:

```
df.rename(columns={,,}, inplace=True)
```

However when I try

```
df.rename(index={'Juan Gonzalez':'Jason','Jorge Sanchez':'George','Miguel Sanz':'Michael'}, inplace=True)
```

It doesn't works, it returns the same dataframe with same indices names

Comment: What is `df.index.tolist()` ?

Comment: This works for me, check your index for spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are some whitespaces in index values.

For remove it use [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.index = df.index.str.strip()
```

Or add parameter `skipinitialspace=True` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

Samples:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""People,age height(cm),weight(kg)

 Juan Gonzalez,22,181,60
 Jorge Sanchez,34,190,84
Miguel Sanz,50,166,59"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), skipinitialspace=True)
print (df)
               People  age height(cm)  weight(kg)
Juan Gonzalez      22             181          60
Jorge Sanchez      34             190          84
Miguel Sanz        50             166          59

print (df.index)
Index(['Juan Gonzalez', 'Jorge Sanchez', 'Miguel Sanz'], dtype='object')

d = {'Juan Gonzalez':'Jason','Jorge Sanchez':'George','Miguel Sanz':'Michael'}
df.rename(index=d, inplace=True)
print (df)
         People  age height(cm)  weight(kg)
Jason        22             181          60
George       34             190          84
Michael      50             166          59
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""People,age height(cm),weight(kg)

 Juan Gonzalez,22,181,60
 Jorge Sanchez,34,190,84
Miguel Sanz,50,166,59"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)
                People  age height(cm)  weight(kg)
 Juan Gonzalez      22             181          60
 Jorge Sanchez      34             190          84
Miguel Sanz         50             166          59

print (df.index)
Index([' Juan Gonzalez', ' Jorge Sanchez', 'Miguel Sanz'], dtype='object')

df.index = df.index.str.strip()

print (df.index)
Index(['Juan Gonzalez', 'Jorge Sanchez', 'Miguel Sanz'], dtype='object')

d = {'Juan Gonzalez':'Jason','Jorge Sanchez':'George','Miguel Sanz':'Michael'}
df.rename(index=d, inplace=True)
print (df)
         People  age height(cm)  weight(kg)
Jason        22             181          60
George       34             190          84
Michael      50             166          59
```